# Uncaught (in promise) syntax error: unexpected end of JSON input with Ruby on Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby on Rails 7 API, that I have been testing out on Postman, the API has several resources one of them being Users. I can create, fetch, edit and delete a user. However when I try to create a frontend to perform the CRUD actions using vanilla Javascript, I only am able to just fetch users, but I can not create, edit or delete, when I try to perform such actions, I get this error:  `uncaught (in promise) syntax error: unexpected end of JSON input`

I have used devise for creating a user, there is no token authentication, just a basic devise registration controller for creating and login a user.

Has anyone experienced such a problem?

USER'S CONTROLLER

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users 
  end

  # PUT|PATCH /users/1
  def edit 
  end
  
  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      render json: { message: "Successfully updated user" }
    else
      head :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def show
    render json: @user
  end

  def destroy 
    @user.destroy
    render json: { message: "Successfully deleted user from database" }
  end

  private 

  def set_user 
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :position, :phone_number, :image, :password)
  end
end
```

RACK CORS

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins "*"

    resource "*",
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

ROUTES

```rb
  devise_for :users
 
  get '/users', to: 'users#index'
  get '/user/:id', to: 'users#show'
  put '/user/:id', to: 'users#update'
  delete '/user/:id', to: 'users#destroy'
```

FRONTEND

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main class="container">
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3 class="my-3">Create User</h3>
        <form class="add-user-form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password-confirmation">Password Confirmation</label>
            <input type="password" id="password-confirmation" class="form-control">
          </div>


          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-3">Sign up</button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
      <table class="table table-striped table-hover mt-4">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Email</th>
              <th scope="col">Position</th>
              <th scope="col">Phone Number</th>
              <th scope="col">Image</th>
              <th scope="col">Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
         <tbody class="user-lists">

         </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

SCRIPT FILE(main.js)

```js
const userList = document.querySelector('.user-lists');
const addUser = document.querySelector('.add-user-form');

const userName = document.querySelector('#name').value;
const userEmail = document.querySelector('#email').value;
const userPassword = document.querySelector('#password').value;
const userPasswordConfirm = document.querySelector('#password-confirmation').value;

const renderUsers = (users) => {
  users.forEach(user => {
    output += `
     <tr>
      <th scope="row">${user.id}</th>
      <td>${user.name}</td>
      <td>${user.email}</td>
      <td>${user.position}</td>
      <td>${user.phone_number}</td>
      <td>${user.image}</td>
      <td><a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a> | <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
     </tr>
    `
  });

  userList.innerHTML = output;
}

const url = 'http://localhost:3000/users'

let output = ''

fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => renderUsers(data))

// Create User - METHOD: POST

addUser.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: userName,
      email: userEmail,
      password: userPassword,
      password_confirmation: userPasswordConfirm
    })
  })
  .then(res => console.log(res.json()))
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .then(data => {
     const dataArr = [];
     dataArr.push(data);
     renderUsers
   })
})
```

Comment: Your first `then` handler returns `undefined`.

Comment: I'm assuming you get this error at the client (JavaScript error) and not at the server. If so, `res.json()` is the most likely cause of the error. Open the browser developer tools, go to the network tab and check the response from the server. It is probably not valid JSON, but the response might tell you what the issue is. You might for example get an 401 (unauthorized), which in turn returns might respond with HTML instead of JSON. You'll have to either configure your server to respond with JSON, even for faulty scenarios like 401, 404, 500, or check for `res.ok` before calling `res.json()`.